# accuracy google cloud speech api

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform

We are having issues with
(1) Google cloud speech api
(2) Google chrome speech api - free version

Below are observations and issues
a) Free version (option 2) shows better accuracy than cloud speech api (option 1). why are results different?

(b) Free version is not consistent and un-deterministic in results. For instance we have observed if 2 people speak with good quality only 1 person speech will be translated.  Again all words spoken may or may not be in text.

(c) It is observed many factors determine quality of speech -> person calmness, good ambiance, angle of holding mic/ear plug, no background noise.  But in real time all this is not possible - how do we make deterministic speech  to text?
Real world will be chaotic.

(d) For best optimal results sample rate is set to 44000Hz (44Khz). But it is observed that some of computers have 44Khz or laptops have 48000Hz(48Khz). Is it okay to normalize at 44Khz (please confirm)

(e) For phone IVR  it  is noticed even if we  speak with clarity - replay back - still google api fails to translate - again at times this works - why is it so?  Note we have seen this for IVR wav file @ 8Khz.

(f) Free version (option 2) can take audio stream without actual wav file creation in REST Post but same is not available with cloud speech api (option 1)

(g) It is seen if speak very few words (1 or 2 words) speech-text fails, it may work only if we speak at-least 5-10 words out of which atleast 2-3 words are incorrectly translated to text.

Kindly help.

Comment: I had similar experience when I tried to transcribe few audio files with Google Speech API. The quality of speech to text is not good enough sometimes its all wrong.